# Prove that if $B\subset \mathbf{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $|B|=\sup\{|A|: A \text{ is a closed bounded subset of $B$}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, supremum-and-infimum

I am currently working on the following exercise

> Prove that if $B\subset \mathbf{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then
>   $$|B|=\sup\{|A|:  A \text{ is a closed bounded subset of $B$}\}.$$

Here is my attempt at the proof so far:

> **Proof.**  If $B\subset \mathbf{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for each
>   $\epsilon>0$, there exists a closed set $A\subset B$ such that
>   $|B\setminus A|<\epsilon$.  Since outer measure is a measure on
>   $(\mathbf{R},\mathcal{L})$, we may write $|B\setminus A|=|B|-|A|$ and
>   thus the statement $|B\setminus A|<\epsilon$ can now be expressed as
>   $|B|-|A|<\epsilon$.  Rearranging this statement further yields
>   $$|B|-\epsilon<|A|.$$  Using this with the fact that
>   $|A|\leq |B|$ (because $A\subset B$), it follows that $$|B|=\sup\{|A|:
>  A \text{ is a closed subset of } B\}.$$

My first question is:  does this proof seem correct so far?  Secondly, if this is indeed the correct approach, how in the world do I establish that $A$ is bounded?

Edit:  The notation $\mathcal{L}$ stands for the set of all Lebesgue measurable sets and the notation $|B|$ and $|A|$ means the *outer measure* of $B$ and $A$, respectively.

Comment: $|B \setminus A| = |B| - |A|$ isn't valid if $|B|$ and $|A|$ are infinite.

Comment: Given $\epsilon\in \Bbb  R^+,$  take $A=\bar A\subset B$ with $|B\setminus A|<\epsilon /3.$ Take an open set   $C\supset A$ with $|C|\leq |A|+\epsilon/2.$ Take  an open set  $D\supset B \setminus A$ with  $|D|\leq \epsilon/2.$ Then $C \cup D$ is open and $C\cup D \supset B$ so  $|B|\leq |C\cup D|$ $\leq |C|+|D|$ $\leq (|A|+\epsilon /2)+\epsilon /2=$ $|A|+\epsilon.$

Comment: $\sup \{|A|: A=\bar A\subset B\}$ is called the inner measure of $B$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I appreciate the help, but I'm having a hard time "reading" your comment.  I guess I see alot of epsilons and I'm not sure why most of them were allowed or necessary.